# Finding the matrix representation of a transform of a polynomial space

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-transformations

I am having trouble with this problem from Sergei Triel's *Linear Algebra Done Wrong*, problem, problem 3.3c:

> **3.3.** For each linear transformation below find [its] matrix 
> ... 
> c) $T : \mathbb{P}_n → \mathbb{P}_n, Tf(t) = f ′(t)$ (find the matrix with respect to the standard basis $1, t, t^2, . . . , t^n$);

I've done all of the previous problems and so far, all of which have only involved vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$, and thus finding the transformation's corresponding matrix has been pretty straightforward. All I've had to do is identify the set of basis vectors and apply the transform to each of them, then align them together to form a matrix.

With this problem, however, I've been getting stuck. To show what I've tried, I assumed that any polynomial $f(t)$ could be expressed as
$$
f(t) = \begin{pmatrix} a_0 \\ a_1 \\ a_2 \\ \vdots \\ a_n \end{pmatrix} = a_0\cdot1 + a_1\cdot t + a_2\cdot t^2 + \ldots + a_n\cdot t^n
$$
Then, applying the transform $f(t)$, we would get
$$
Tf(t) = a_0\cdot (0) + a_1\cdot(1) + a_2\cdot (2t) + \ldots + a_n \cdot (nt^{n-1})
$$
with each of the objects in parenthesis representing a transformed basis vector. However, the fact that the resulting matrix would be
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1& 2t & \ldots & nt^{n-1} \end{pmatrix}
$$
which seemed odd to me. Looking back, it's clear that what I thought were "basis vectors" (i.e. $1, t, \ldots t^n$) were all just scalars (as far as my understanding goes). I'm tempted to replace each of those attempts at basis vectors with $(0, \ldots, 0, t^k, 0, \ldots, 0)^T$ for $0 \leq k \leq n$, but I'm not sure if I'm correct.

As a final note, I did end up googling the answer and I found [this](https://linearalgebras.com/ladw-exercise-1-3-3.html), but this approach does not make sense to me—why do they choose to represent a generic polynomial from $\mathbb{P}_n$ with $(1, t, t^2, \ldots, t^n)^T$? It doesn't seem like it can be generalized to any polynomial.

In all, it seems like my problem stems from a misunderstanding of what vectors from $\mathbb{P}_n$ actually are—and, subsequently, a misunderstanding of what the basis vectors from this space are, so I think that's what I need help with. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The basis vectors are **functions** $e_k(t) = t^k$, $k=0,...,n$. You have $Te_0 = 0$, $Te_k = k e_{k-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing out a polynomial from $\mathbb{P}_n$, $t$ is what we call a *formal variable*, meaning that it is not a scalar value, and it does not represent a specific quantity. Formal variables can be manipulated in a bunch of ways, most of which should be familiar to you if you're comfortable with standard algebra and calculus. Even the constant term $t^0 = 1$ is playing a special role here outside of its usual value as an integer or real number.

The standard basis of $\mathbb{P}_n$ is the set $\{1, t, t^2, \ldots, t^n\}$ because we can write any polynomial of degree (up to) $n$ as a linear combination of these just by reading off the coefficients. In fact, there is a direct correspondence between $\mathbb{P}_n$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, so that the vector $(3, 4, 2)$ (for example) maps to the quadratic $3 + 4t + 2t^2$.

So when you differentiated $f(t)$ and got $a_1 \cdot 1 + (2 a_2) \cdot t + \ldots + (n a_n) \cdot t^{n-1}$, if we look at what happened to the coefficients we essentially mapped $(a_0, a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_{n-1}, a_n) \rightarrow (a_1, 2a_2, 3a_3, \ldots, n a_n, 0)$. Notice that essentially the coefficient of each basis vector gets shifted to the left, along with a scalar factor. The coefficient of $1$ disappears, and the transformed vector has an implicit coefficient of $t^n$ of zero.

It is important to be able to demonstrate that $T$ is indeed a linear transformation, but that's fairly simple if you're already comfortable with the fact that $(af + bg)' = af' + bg'$, where $a$ and $b$ are constants and $f$ and $g$ are suitable functions. But having done so, we *know* that a linear transformation is completely defined by its effect on a set of basis vectors, and so we *can* use the fact that $\frac{d}{dt} t^k = k t^{k-1}$ as the defining operation of our transformation.

Answer (score 1):

$T(1) = 0\\
T(t) = 1\\
T(t^2) = 2t\\
T(t^3) = 3t^2$

$T = \pmatrix{0&1&0&0&\cdots\\0&0&2&0&\cdots\\0&0&0&3&\cdots\\\vdots&&&\ddots}$